# Sending Message and Attachment with Perl

Tags: perl

I have some emails from **Mail::POP3Client** that I need to send (including attachments) to another email address (essentially, as if it were forwarded from a common email client).

I'm not very familiar with Perl, so I've been looking into this for a while. I'm not sure of the best way to do this; do I need to use *RetrieveToFile* and then send it with **MIME::Lite**? Will that be readable by a human and include attachments?

It seems like there has to be a simpler way that I haven't discovered yet. Am I on the right track?

Comment: The `MIME::Lite` documentation recommends no longer using `MIME::Lite`.

Answer (score -1):

I've done similar things with MIME-tools, which is a similar package. At the time I did that, MIME-Lite didn't exist. But I am sure that MIME-tools can handle what you ask. I can't imagine that MIME-Lite shouldn't be able to do something similar.

Answer (score -1):

Forwarding like a desktop mail client does consists of two parts:

1. email munging

   Use [Courriel::Builder](http://p3rl.org/Courriel%3a%3aBuilder) to create a new email. Attach the email that you originally received. The appropriate `mime_type` parameter for the attached email is [`message/rfc822`](http://enwp.org/Multipart_message#Content-Type).
2. email sending

   Use [Email::Sender](http://p3rl.org/Email%3a%3aSender).

---

You probably want to [redirect](http://email.about.com/cs/usingemail/a/redirect.htm), not forward the email, though, so that the original sender stays the same and the recipient can easily reply.